# Session expires after closing jquery dialog

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

In my web application I use jquery dialogs to open popups.
The function used to perform this task is this:

```
function OpenPopup(popupTarget, width, height, params, onOpenFunction, onCloseFunction, popupElement){

// some code to parse the parameters
//`popupElement` is a div with `style="display: none;"`
// included in a master page which every page inherits from

    $(popupElement).dialog(
{
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    height: height,
    width: width,
    modal: true,
    open: onOpenFunction,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    close: function (e)
    {
        var popupResult = $(this).dialog("option", "notification");

        $(this).dialog("destroy");

        if (!isHTMLElement)
            popupFrame.css("visibility", "hidden");

        if (jQuery.isFunction(onCloseFunction))
        {
            var funct = eval(onCloseFunction);
            funct(popupResult);
        }
    }
});

$(popupElement).dialog("open");
}
```

This is the function that calls the above method:

```
function FiltroNotifiche(){
params = "";

OpenPopup("~/manage/Popup/FiltroNotifiche.aspx", 450, 350, params, function (e) { }, function (strNotification)
{
    OnPopupReturn(true, strNotification, function ()
    {
        __doPostBack('UpdatePanel', 'Filtro=true');
    });
});
}

function OnPopupReturn(bRefresh, strNotification, senderFunction){
// this function parses strNotification and if, successful, calls:
    var funct = eval(senderFunction);
    funct();

}
```

Inside the popup I use the `ICallbackEventHandler`callback interface.

The problem is that after opening and closing the popup (I can see the callback being executed and all), whatever I do next I'm getting kicked out, most likely because the session has expired.

A strange thing that I noticed is that this happens *only* if I get to the page that opens the popup (GestioneNotifiche.aspx) via the menu control, because if I get to there through a button PostBackUrl in another page, this doesn't happen, and the session lives happily!

The menu has an xml data source and these bindings:

```
<DataBindings>
  <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="Menu" TextField="Text" Selectable="false" />
  <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="MenuItem" NavigateUrlField="NavigateUrl" TextField="Text" ValueField="Value" />
</DataBindings>
```

This is the menu item:

`<MenuItem Value="" Text="Gestione notifiche" NavigateUrl="~/manage/GestioneNotifiche/GestioneNotifiche.aspx"  />`

I did notice the call through the menu has `Request.HttpMethod = "GET"`, while via postback it is (rather obviously) `"POST"`. Could this be the significant? I don't really know much about the difference between GET and POST.

Thank you

Comment: What makes you think session is actually expiring. After being "kicked out", can you go back to the address and using debug, check if session contains variables you expect it to contain?

Comment: With "kicked out" I meant I am being redirected to the login page of my app; I cannot simply type the address and load the page again

Comment: so it seems your authentication is being cleared...not session. Do you have some code in the page_load that is being used to determine if a user is authenticated and redirecting if he is not? If so, paste it in.

Comment: You were right. The code is too nested to be explained clearly, but the problem was that during the onunload event a function was called that triggered the logout. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: I added as an answer so that you can mark it is as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your problem is that authentication is being cleared and not your session. Check your page_load event to see if you are doing anything differently between a GET and POST request that would result in clearing the authentication.